# WordPress 4.4.2 Update not working

Tags: permissions, ftp, automatic-updates

I would like to use Auto Update feature to update wordpress. I see this question was asked 5 years ago 
I would prefer doing the upgrade using Automatic update instead of manual process and fix what's broken or the cause in my environment

### My Environment

- FTP is enabled
- I am able to install themese using the same ftp account
- Permissions on website directory drwxr-xr-x

### Sequence of steps

when i hit Update now and then type ftp password and hit proceed

Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.4.2-partial-1.zip…

Unpacking the update…

Verifying the unpacked files…

The update could not be unpacked

Installation Failed

### What i have tried

- Change permissions to 777
- Found this on wordpress.org "one-click updates without entering FTP credentials" so my website does ask for FTP credentials, not sure how to make it one-click

Comment: I had a similar problem. Wordpress upgrade failed with an unpacking issue.
It was a Vsftpd 3.0.2 bug in fact on Debian. Now I use unstable 3.0.3 and it works perfectly. Reference: http://insanepengu.in/wordpress-update-could-not-be-unpacked-fix-on-debian-vsftpd-3-0-2/

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the ownership of the directory

Current Ownership was
username:www-data

Changed it to 
www=data:www-data

after this it's not asking for my ftp password anymore and update is working with just one click

Reference

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-install-asks-for-ftp-details

Comment: from the CLI, that would be `chown -f -R user:group /path/to/folder` see https://codepad.co/snippet/tLAOg9VQ